# WINE How to make .exe shortcut with parameters?

Tags: shortcut, wine

I have an .exe file that I would like to run with the following parameters:

```
-no-cef-sandbox
```

In the WineStaging terminal I would use the following command to run the .exe:

```
#!/bin/bash
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-gwent/ wine ~/.wine-gwent/drive_c/Program\ Files/GOG\ Galaxy/Games/Gwent/Gwent.exe -no-cef-sandbox
```

I'd like to run the .exe file without having to run the command in WineStaging every time. I suspect I will need to either create a shortcut of some kind or a .command file to run with Wine.

FYI, am using WineStaging on a Mac.

Thanks for the help!